# enableIvy option is not showing in tsconfig file while upgrading from angular 8 to angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-upgrade

I tried to upgrade angular project from version 8 to 9. After upgrade, i didnot find enableIvy option in tsconfig file. Shall i need to add enableIvy as true inside tsconfig manually ? or Default it is true ?

Answer (score 1):

In angular 9 its enabled by default. In docs

> Ivy is the code name for Angular's next-generation compilation and
>   rendering pipeline. With the version 9 release of Angular, the new
>   compiler and runtime instructions are used by default instead of the
>   older compiler and runtime, known as View Engine.

Comment: Ok, so no need for enbleIvy as true in tsconfig correct?

Comment: In my project when we did the migration from 7 to 9. Ivy was enabled by default.

Comment: In your project any property like enableIvy in tsconfig appears after upgrading from 7 to 9

Comment: Nope. I haven't seen such flag

Comment: Ok, same in my project also. But some reference ( not angular doc) saying about need to enableIvy as true. I got confused. For ensuring Ivy enabled or not I posted this question. Thanks Arun.

Comment: Hello, I am migrating from angular 8 to angular 9, I want to disable Ivy as it is affecting many existing functionalities of my project. I am not able to find the option enableIvy in my tsconfig file. Is there any other way of disabling Ivy in in angular 9?

Comment: @DeekshaMulgaonkar Please have a look

https://angular.io/guide/ivy#opting-out-of-ivy-in-version-9